# YoY growth in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get  YoY percent growth in Tableau. I would like to see 2015 Jan Unique customers vs 2014 Jan Customers and so on and so forth till the last set of data.

When doing this in Sample super store, I get the following viz. 
[image]

What I am looking is for a continuous view where the years are not broken down. Something similar to this:
[image]

Any suggestions on how I can get to the final stage. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just use the year in columns, you should get the desired result (Remove the month from column). If it is still creating issues, you can create a calculated column which just has the year and use it in the visualization. The following link should guide you through the steps (Except its a bar chart, so the year would have been converted to discrete. You should be fine with continuous):

https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2015/09/17/how-make-yoy-bar-charts-tableau/

Hope this helps.